# iOS Facebook Like Button Not Resizing

Tags: ios, facebook

I am setting up an iOS app and have implemented a Facebook like button. Problem is, when I try to adjust the size according to their documentation found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/like-button#adjust-button-layout), it just does not resize. Here's my setup code which is all the code that uses the like button:

```
(ViewController.h)

@property FBSDKLikeControl* likeButton;

(ViewController.m)

@synthesize likeButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ...

    likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 128, 64)];
    likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/mypage";
}

- (void)showLikeButton {
    [self.view addSubview:likeButton];
}

- (void)hideLikeButton {
    [likeButton removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When showLikeButton is called (which is after the app has been running a little while), the button shows up as expected, but no matter what size I initialize the button with, it doesn't change its size. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to create custom one so whatever you like can be done.

Comment: From what I have noticed, the actual size of the blue button is fixed. When you change the frame of the button, it only seems to affect the width of the area within which the text that follows the button is displayed i.e. `x.. people like this` .

Answer (score 3):

Use FBSDKLikeButton in place of FBSDKLikeControl. It inherits from UIButton and responds to sizing changes, although the image resolution suffers.